# How to sort this specific string array by using the following set of rules(?):

Tags: c

Yes, I'm a newbie and my uncle has challenged me to use the function:

```
void sortStrings(char str[], const char* delim){...}
```

to sort the given char array **str** in a way that every char from **delim** that shows up in **str** will separate a group of chars in **str** thus making them the words you need to sort by hex value. In the process I also need to replace those word separating chars from **delim** with ';'.

**The rules are:** I may only use the library `<stdio.h>` and I can't use malloc/realloc.
Apparently this should be done with an O notation of n^2 (n being the amount of words in str, not chars)

and here's an example of an input and output:

***input:***

char str[] = "aaa*test,hello.world*abcd.zzz";
sortDelim(str, ",.*")

***output:*** str is now: "aaa;abcd;hello;test;world;zzz"

*Well, I've managed it now eventually, the bubble sort thing kinda helped so tyvm for that :)*
note: I'll leave this thread here in case anyone wants to take this challenge on himself? It ain't easy I promise :P If you think I should delete it or add the finished code then just ask(Please don't deduct my rep even more ><)

Comment: I'm glad you got it working and that you found my hints helpful.  Don't be discouraged by the down votes... every single programmer here struggled initially with small puzzles like that, nothing worthwhile is easy, programming is rewarding if you have the mind for it, and the will to persevere.  Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are off to a good start.  After your second for loop you have

1. replaced all delimiters with semicolon
2. you know how many words there are, `size`
3. you know how many letters each word has, `letters`

One observation is that you have allocated `letters` to be 1000 entries.  That seems like enough, but is it really?  How do you know how many words there are in str?  You don't.  And you can't use malloc to allocate dynamically, so perhaps you need to look for an algorithm that doesn't require that lookup table?  You need an algorithm that works `in place`

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In-place_algorithm

What's next?  You need to sort the words.  There are many sorting algorithms.  You want something simple, and are allowed complexity O(n^2).  Here's a list of sorting algorithms:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm

Notice that in the table, under 'other notes' it tells you that some algorithms are "Tiny code size", that sounds good.  Sort the table first by 'other notes' then by 'Average' complexity (click on the triangle in the column header).  You now have two algorithms that use a method 'exchanging' (that means `in place`), with `Tiny code size` and average complexity O(n^2), these wikipedia links explain how they work, and include [pseudocode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudocode) to get you started:

- [Bubble sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort)
- [Gnome sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gnome_sort)

Take your pick and try your hand at it.

**Hint:** you probably want a subroutine that exchanges (swaps) two consecutive words if the first word compares greater than the second word.  This can be done `in place`.

Suppose you have

```
abcd;aaa
```

The first word is greater than the second word, you need to detect that, and swap the words so you end up with

```
aaa;abcd
```

Here's a diagram that will give you the general idea.

[image]